# Unable to describe my keys from aws cli to aws accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

Whenever I try to describe my keys to confirm that I could access my AWS accounts from the AWS cli - I see this error:

> usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
>   To see help text, you can run:
>
> aws help
>    `aws <command> help`
>    `aws <command> <subcommand> help`

Sometimes I see this error:

Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Can someone figure out this issue?

Comment: I normally use `aws sts get-caller-identity` to check if AWS CLI is configured and with which account/credentials.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the `aws cli` to use credentials. There are a couple ways to do this.

### aws configure command

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html#cli-quick-configuration

```
$ aws configure
AWS Access Key ID [None]: AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
AWS Secret Access Key [None]: wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
Default region name [None]: us-west-2
Default output format [None]: json
```

### Environment Variables

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY
$ export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have not mentioned your real access key and secret key. If you did mention, I'm assuming you have already made it inactive. :)

Comment: @Pacifist_AWS its straight from the AWS documentation which is why if you look at the keys it says "EXAMPLE" and "EXAMPLEKEY" at the end. so no.... not my keys.